# loop through array fails

Tags: c++, arrays

Can someone explain why doesn't this code work with last element ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main(){
    const int n = 10, m = 10;
    int asd[n][m] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9 } };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][m] << endl;
        sum += asd[i][m];
    }
    cout << "Sum of first col " << sum << endl;
}
```

If I remove `n` and `m`, and set array `asd[10][10]` - that works fine, why ?

Comment: `asd[i][10]` is out of bounds for all values of `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're printing an out-of-range element in the last iteration (and possibly getting every element wrong in the previous ones)

```
cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][10] << endl;
                                           ^^
```

This will work instead (assuming I correctly interpreted what you're trying to do):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][0] << endl;
    sum += asd[i][0];
}
cout << "Sum of first col " << sum << endl; // 10
```

Bonus tips:

- main should return int:

  ```
  int main() {
  ```
- Using `using namespace std;` will pollute the global namespace

Answer (score 1):

Change this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][m] << endl;
    sum += asd[i][m];
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][0] << endl;
    sum += asd[i][0];
}
```

provided that you are calculating the sum of the elements of the first column.

Take into account that function main shall have return type `int`

```
int main()
```

As for your question then your program has undefined behaviour. For example expression

`asd[0][m]` is equivalent to `asd[1][0]`.

and expression asd[9][m] is equivalent to asd[10][0]. So all depends on what is stored in memory beyond the array.

Answer (score 0):

As the Array contians only 10 rows hence only you will be having index till 9.So it will be out of bound

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][m] << endl;
    sum += asd[i][m];
}
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Array[" << i << "] => " << asd[i][0] << endl;
    sum += asd[i][0];
}
```

If you want to print for all the columns sum then you can use the below code

```
 for (int j=0;j<m;j++){
  int sum=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      sum += asd[i][j];
    }
   cout << "Sum of" << j <<"col " << sum << endl;
 }
```